# Adding order by to a query is slowing down the query even after Indexing

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, order-by, optimization, query-performance

While joining columns with huge data even after indexing the column order by is slowing down the query. Without order by query is executing within 2 secs. But with order by query is taking 145 secs. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT  
    pd.message_id,
    pd.Receipt_Time_Stamp,
    pd.shift_id,
    pd.Tunnel_ID,
    pd.Package_Number,
    pd.Package_Read_Status,
    pd.Iseq_Number,
    pd.SxS_Status,
    pd.host_message,
    pd.package_gap,
    pd.Parcel_Length,
    pd.Parcel_Width,
    pd.Parcel_Height,
    pd.Image_Files,
    t.tunnel_name,
    s.shift_name 
FROM 
    fm_package_db.dla_package_details pd  
    force index(dl_dla_package_details_receipt_time_stamp_idx)  
    JOIN 
    fm_local_db.as_fm_tunnel_master t   
    force index(dl_as_fm_tunnel_master_tunnel_id_idx)   
    ON pd.Tunnel_ID = t.Tunnel_ID 
    JOIN 
    fm_local_db.as_fm_shift_info s 
    force index(dl_as_fm_shift_info_shift_id_idx) 
    ON s.shift_id = pd.shift_id 
    where pd.message_id in 
    (Select distinct b.Message_ID from dla_more_bar_codes  b 
    force index(dl_dla_more_bar_codes_message_id_idx,dl_dla_more_bar_codes_bar_code_number_idx,
    dl_dla_more_bar_codes_bar_code_idx) 
    JOIN fm_package_db.dla_more_devices d 
    force index(dl_dla_more_devices_message_id_idx,dl_dla_more_devices_device_id_idx) 
    ON b.message_id = d.message_id
 where (b.bar_code_number = 1
     or b.bar_code_number = 2)and bar_code like '%9%' and (d.device_id = 2 or d.device_id = 3
     or d.device_id = 8
     or d.device_id = 1005
     or d.device_id = 1021
     or d.device_id = 1049
     or d.device_id = 1057
     or d.device_id = 1081) ) 
    and
    pd.receipt_time_stamp between '2015-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-30 23:59:59' 
    and  
    pd.Message_Type = 'PackageInfo' 
    AND (pd.Tunnel_ID = '1') 
    AND (pd.shift_id = 1 or pd.shift_id = 2 
    or pd.shift_id = 3) 
    and pd.receipt_time_stamp like '%2015%' 
    and pd.Package_Number like '%5%' 
    and pd.Package_Read_Status like '%R%' 
    and pd.Iseq_Number like '%5%' 
    and pd.host_message like '%5%' 
    and pd.Parcel_Length like '%0%' 
    and pd.Parcel_Width like '%0%' 
    and pd.Parcel_Height like '%0%'   
    and  s.shift_name like '%S%' 
    and  t.tunnel_name like '%T%' 
    order by pd.receipt_time_stamp asc 
    LIMIT  0,25;
```

The explain is as follows:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  t   ref dl_as_fm_tunnel_master_tunnel_id_idx    dl_as_fm_tunnel_master_tunnel_id_idx    8   const   1   Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  pd  range   dl_dla_package_details_receipt_time_stamp_idx   dl_dla_package_details_receipt_time_stamp_idx   5   NULL    1958726 Using index condition; Using where
1   SIMPLE  s   ref dl_as_fm_shift_info_shift_id_idx    dl_as_fm_shift_info_shift_id_idx    8   fm_package_db.pd.shift_id   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  b   ref dl_dla_more_bar_codes_message_id_idx,dl_dla_more_bar_codes_bar_code_number_idx  dl_dla_more_bar_codes_message_id_idx    8   fm_package_db.pd.Message_ID 1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  d   ref dl_dla_more_devices_message_id_idx,dl_dla_more_devices_device_id_idx    dl_dla_more_devices_message_id_idx  8   fm_package_db.pd.Message_ID 2   Using where; FirstMatch(s)
```

In profiling it say's sending data is taking more time. 
Create Table Queries are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `dla_package_details` (
  `Message_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Receipt_Time_Stamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Message_Type` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Message_Status` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'P',
  `Site_Code` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tunnel_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shift_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Package_Number` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Package_Read_Status` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Iseq_Number` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Host_Message` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Eseq_Number` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bar_Code_1` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Bar_Code_2` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Bar_Code_3` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Bar_Code_4` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Bar_Code_5` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Bar_Code_6` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `More_bar_Codes` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'N',
  `Dev_1_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_2_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_3_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_4_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_5_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_6_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_7_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_8_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_9_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_10_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_11_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_12_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_13_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_14_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_15_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_16_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_17_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_18_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_19_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_20_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_21_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Dev_22_Details` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `More_Devices` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'N',
  `Nbr_Short_Parcels` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Nbr_Short_Gaps` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Nbr_Lost_Barcodes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Trigger_Length` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Package_Gap` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Conveyor_Speed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SxS_Status` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parcel_Length` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parcel_Width` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parcel_Height` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parcel_Linear_Units` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `LFT_Dimensions` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Parcel_Volume` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parcel_Volume_Units` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parcel_Weight` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parcel_Weight_Units` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `LFT_Parcel_Weight` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LFT_Parcel_Weight_Units` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Overlap_Prev` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Overlap_Next` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Image_Files` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Decode_Info` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `Device_Read_Result` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `unix_receipt_time_stamp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Message_type_id` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Message_ID`),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_message_type_idx` (`Message_Type`),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_shift_id_idx` (`shift_id`),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_package_number_idx` (`Package_Number`),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_package_read_status_idx` (`Package_Read_Status`),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_iseq_number_idx` (`Iseq_Number`),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_host_message_idx` (`Host_Message`(255)),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_package_gap_idx` (`Package_Gap`),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_sxs_status_idx` (`SxS_Status`),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_parcel_length_idx` (`Parcel_Length`),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_parcel_width_idx` (`Parcel_Width`),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_parcel_height_idx` (`Parcel_Height`),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_unix_receipt_time_stamp_idx` (`unix_receipt_time_stamp`),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_tunnel_id_idx` (`Tunnel_ID`),
  KEY `dl_dla_package_details_receipt_time_stamp_idx` (`Receipt_Time_Stamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What can be done to optimize this query?

Comment: Welcome to the forums. In future, please don't hesitate to use the code formatting options at the top of the question window (Block Quote/Code Sample)! Take the tour and check out the "help us to help you" blog (both at the bottom left of the page). Now, to your question, could you please post a SHOW CREATE TABLE dla_package_details\G.

Comment: `pd.receipt_time_stamp like '%2015%'`? This makes any index pretty useless. Why not `pd.receipt_time_stamp >= '2015-01-01' AND pd.receipt_time_stamp < '2016-01-01'` so index can be used?

Comment: We are displaying the result in a grid where in we are allowing the user to do a search on each column. So we have to allow a wild card search also on     pd.receipt_time_stamp .

Comment: Just noticed that you also have `pd.receipt_time_stamp between '2015-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-30 23:59:59'`.  A wild card search on a datetime/timestamp column makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me you are forcing too many indexes instead of letting optimizer do its work and maybe just push it a little bit in the right direction.

One of those forced indexes or something else made it use t as base table instead of pd - that means order by pd.receipt_time_stamp has to be resolved by filesort on temp table (and text column in temp table means it has to go to disk - no in-memory table - [manual info on temp tables usage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-temporary-tables.html)).

You could try "... STRAIGHT_JOIN fm_local_db.as_fm_tunnel_master t " to make myslq use "right" base table and sort by index.

I would try to remove all "force index" too to see what happens, maybe the straight join is not needed at all, but thats just guessing on my side.

Comment: Thank you so much the Straight Joins resolved the problem. But still we are allowing the user to sort by tunnel name which is a column in straight joined table, which is still slower. Any workarounds for that.

Comment: @Nisha did you try to remove those "force index" ? was there any effect (positive or negative) of doing so? In ideal case optimizer should be able to decide which way to go without forcing and straight joins, but sometimes things are not ideal, it is better to ignore index which you know is very bad for this query than to force one optimal in one case but not in other. Did you run "analyze table" lately (may take some time on big table) and "show index from <table>" to see statistics are not very bad?

Comment: I tried with "force index" (dl_dla_package_details_receipt_time_stamp_idx) which had no impact on the result retrieval time. The straight join mainly did the trick there,  however when I tried to query for little older data ,it is consuming time. I have around 4Million data and when i tried to query for some 1Million old , it is taking about 40 Sec. The newest data is getting pulled within a second. Any reason behind such a delay? I got to know that data retrieval without order by clause is very fast and problem is only with the order by.

Comment: @Nisha you mean "order by ... limit 1000000, X" ?

Comment: yes that is right. order by Receipt_Time_Stamp Desc limit 0,25;

Comment: @Nisha I mean when you say "to query for some 1Million old" - did you "skip" the newer ones using some WHERE condition or LIMIT with big offset ?

Comment: yes I have where criteria added to my query to retrieve older set of data. I have to retrieve newest 25 items from older date , so am doing descending sort here.

Comment: @Nisha so "WHERE pd.receipt_time_stamp < "some old date" ORDER BY pd.receipt_time_stamp desc LIMIT 0,25" ? the straight join should work well with it in case pd.receipt_time_stamp is properly indexed (probably with other columns in one multicolumn index (all those with = before it)

Answer (score 0):

First the ORDER BY uses index on first table columns. But EXPLAIN shows your first table is t not pd. So use STRAIGHT JOIN.

Second EXPLAIN shows INDEX TYPE IS RANGE. So it doesn't uses other indexes for ORDER BY. It uses index on between condition and if it is multi column index then order matters, and if condition is on first column (on multi column index) but order by on second column then it will also use that index. Example

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` char(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CountryCode` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `District` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Population` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `CountryCode` (`CountryCode`),
  KEY `District` (`District`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4080 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Hitesh> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM city WHERE ID BETWEEN 10 AND 20 ORDER BY DISTRICT \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: city
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 11
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
```

EXPLAIN shows your mysql-server is sorting the records on the disk. It is using temporary table & it would slow because this is not using index.

For this scenario, use STRAIGHT JOIN for first table and CREATE INDEX on   (pd.Tunnel_ID, Receipt_Time_Stamp)

Answer (score 0):

Don't have dozens of `TEXT` fields in a table.

Don't have "arrays" in a table.  By that I mean don't have columns `Dev_1_Details` .. `Dev_22_Details`.  Instead have another table with `Message_ID bigint(20) NOT NULL` (for JOINing) and `Dev_Details TEXT NOT NULL` and (optionally) a `TINYINT UNSIGNED` to number them.

Avoid `FORCE INDEX` -- Today it might help with some values; tomorrow it will bite you by doing the 'wrong' thing.

Don't use `in ( SELECT .. )`, it optimizes poorly; change it to a `JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...`.

Don't use BIGINT (8 bytes) when INT (4 bytes) or something smaller will suffice.

These changes will help performance in various ways, possibly including your original question.

Suggested index:

```
on `pd`: INDEX(Message_Type, receipt_time_stamp)
on `b`: INDEX(bar_code_number, message_id)
on `b`: INDEX(message_id, bar_code_number)
on `d`: INDEX(device_id, message_id)
on `d`: INDEX(message_id, device_id)
```

Notice that all of those are "composite" indexes.  Learn how `INDEX(a,b)` is *not* the same as `INDEX(a)` + `INDEX(b)`.

When adding `INDEX(Message_Type, receipt_time_stamp)`, `DROP KEY dl_dla_package_details_message_type_idx (Message_Type)` as being redundant.  That is, `INDEX(a)` is not needed when you have `INDEX(a, ...)` because it the former is a prefix of the latter.

Indexes on 'low cardinality' fields (such as *status) are rarely useful if that is the only column in the index.

If you still have issues after making most of those changes; we can dig further.